# Android - Read text from file and add it to a LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, android, file, key-value

Im building a function which gets a country name and returns its country code (iso/telephone prefix). I added to my project (to the root of the app) a text file which holds key-value pairs of countries and their country code in the following format:

```
"Abkhazia":7840,
"Abkhazia":7940,
"Afghanistan":93,
"Albania":355,
"Algeria":213,
```

The user enters a country name in an `EditText` box and the function should return the code.

```
editTextCountryInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextCountryInput);
getCountryCode(editTextCountryInput.getText().toString());
```

The function:

```
private int getCountryCode(String countryName){
    try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("countries.txt")));
        String inputLine = null;
        LinkedHashMap<String,String> dictionary = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
        try{
            while((inputLine = reader.readLine()) !=null){
                String[] words = inputLine.split(":"); //split each line by : delimiter

                for(String word: words){
                    Log.i("splitting ", " line");
                    dictionary.put(word,?); //what should be the second arg?
                }
            }
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int countryCode =(int) dictionary.get(countryName);
    return countryCode;
}
```

I want to read each line of the text file, split each line where the delimiter is (":") and place each split key-value pair in the `LinkedHashMap`. 2 problems:
1. I get an error `java.io.FileNotFoundException: countries.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`. When i tested the file for `absolute path` i got "/countries.txt" - but it still fails for that error.
2. After I split the read line using the `String.split(":")` method, I dont know how to store the two part inside the hashMap in a key-value manner.
This is the code i use to determine the absolute path:

```
File f = new File("countries2.txt");
        Log.i("abs path: ", f.getAbsolutePath());
```

EDIT:
I created a new `assets` folder in Android Studio (right click on the app -> new Assets folder -> finish) and placed my `countries.txt` file, but I'm still getting the FileNotFound exception.

Comment: Remove the for loop. `dictionary.put(words[0],words[1]);` You could remove the quotes before splitting.

Comment: `I added to my project (to the root of the app) a text file`. How did you do that exactly? And where is that file now? You use a relative path where you should use an absolute path.

Comment: If you call that function every time there is no need to construct a hashmap which you would trow away anyway. Just compare if words[0] equals the wanted country.

Comment: I just dragged the txt file into the the project. I tested the path using the 'getAbsolutePath' method and got "/countries.txt" - so this must be the absolute path. In order to extract the country code I need to play it inside the Map, to first i need to construct it, that was my initial thought.

Comment: `I just dragged the txt file into the the project.`. Sorry but i cannot see what you did. You should be much more esxact. And which IDE do you use. /countries.txt can not be an absolute path. Maybe on a rooted device.

Comment: I use Android Studio. I tried placing the text file under different folders, got the absolute file with the mentioned above method and used that as a path. Clearly i got that wrong. Where\how should i add an external text file to the project?

Comment: In the assets directory of your IDE. But I wonder what code you used to get the AbsolutePath.

Comment: Please see the updated post, i added the code i used to get the absolute path.

Comment: Yes that code does not what you think it does. So useless. Put your file in the assets directory. Then in getCountryCode() you only have to change the first code line to use an InputStream from AssetsManager.

Comment: `but I'm still getting the FileNotFound exception`. Did you change the code of getCountryCode() as i suggested? Google for `android studio assets folder location` and `android open file from assets`.

Comment: Got this working, thanks for directing me.

Answer (score 1):

1. That's because [FileReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html) cannot find your txt file.
2. You could try:

   ```
   String[] words = inputLine.split(":"); //split each line by : delimiter
   dictionary.put(words[0],words[1]); //what should be the second arg?
   ```

`words[0]` will hold name, while `words[1]` will hold number.

Answer (score 0):

i think first problem is very simple that telling you file not found and and second problem you can use array for that e.g

```
    String[] a ="this iskey:and its value".split(":");
    System.out.println(a[0]);
    System.out.println(a[1]);
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String key =a[0];
    String value =a[1];
    map.put(key, value);
```